# How to use Buefy's tooltip with content slot

Tags: vue.js, buefy

I'm trying to use [Buefy's tooltip](https://buefy.org/documentation/tooltip/) with a content slot, so insted of using the `label prop` to set tooltip's text, I could use HTML tags to format my text.

I tried to check the component [source code](https://github.com/buefy/buefy/blob/dev/src/components/tooltip/Tooltip.vue), and there is indeed a content slot, but it is not working. Here is my code:

```
        <b-tooltip
          position="is-left"
        >
          <template #content>
            My <b>content</b> here
          </template>
          <b-input
            v-on:keyup.native.enter="onEnter"
            type="password"
            v-model="password"
            placeholder="Enter Password"
            password-reveal
            class="custom-input-style password-field"
          ></b-input>
        </b-tooltip>
```

Comment: See the documentation here: https://buefy.org/documentation/tooltip#custom-content

Answer (score 0):

Check your buefy version, if it is below 0.9.0 then it won't work